# Add columns next to the cell I clicked in before running the macro

Tags: excel, vba

I hope everyone is doing well? 
I am currently working on an Excel VBA task (my first time working with VBA, so I am sorry if I do ask silly questions). One thing I am researching for almost 2 days now and I can't find a solution anywhere is how to add columns in an Excel sheet via VBA.
To be more precisely: I don't want to add columns in one specific position (e.g. "A:B") but rather to click in a cell, run the macro and it will add 77 columns right next to this cell. 
E.g. say I click into cell B2 and run the macro, I would like to have 77 empty columns from column C onwards. I was looking into "ActiveCell" as well but didn't get anywhere.

The macro I found that was the most helpful so far is this:

```
Sub C_SpaltenEinfügen()
Dim Start As Integer
Start = 2
Range(Cells(1, Start), Cells(1, Start + 77)).EntireColumn.Insert
End Sub
```

But I am not able to change it from Start = 2 to ActiveCell or anything close to that, so it will only start from column B. As the data set is quite large (currently from Column A to ARW), calculating all starting points wouldn't be very efficent.

I really do appreciate your time and help!

Thanks so much in advance,
Lea

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you want 77 rows added, you would add current through 76 rows, because the first row is the initial insert.  This would do that, via double clicking on Row 1:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Row = 1 Then
        Range(Columns(Target.Column + 1), Columns(Target.Column + 1 + 76)).Insert
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

You stated that you wanted this to be to *the right* if where you select, so the `.Column+1` offsets the column so you can work with that on the right, e.g., you double click on B1 and you insert 77 columns in front of column C.  I left the +1 on the remainder of the range for clarity.

The use of `Cancel=True` after the insert is so you don't enter the cell you double clicked to begin editing it.

Note where I selected the `BeforeDoubleClick`... After selecting the sheet module for `Sheet1 (Sheet1)`, I used the drop downs, select `Worksheet` in the left, then the right I selected `BeforeDoubleClick`:
[image]

Comment: Forgot to add an important error you may run into... if you have data that will be pushed to the far edge and exceed the maximum column count, you will have an error... so don't just go double clicking away for the sake of it!

Comment: Thank you so much! That was very helpful indeed. :-)

Comment: @Lea if that resolved your answer, please select the Check-Mark to the left of the post so it is marked as `Answered` in the question log.